c4model is before or after BOA/Epic Architecture?
c4model.com provides a very good architecture standards with its 4Cs for various audiences. However, with Agile which has Business Outcomes (BO) Architecture --> EPIC Architecture, etc. are required. Hence, do let me know your opinion whether c4model is relevant at which stage. Is it any stage it can be brought into or or post BO Arch and EPIC Arch?

After conducting some research and consultations, I discovered that the C4 model is typically utilized after the BOA and EPIC architectures. It is generally applied at the level of user stories in Agile. Nonetheless, adopting the C4 model is a good standard practice, as it offers abstraction for diverse audiences at different levels.
